# How do I use ng-filter without changing $index on ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Currently if I filter, the $index also updates. So if there are 500 results, and I filter the ranking, also updates. How do I have an index column that doesn't update?

Here's my code:

```
<input ng-model="query.teamName" /></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:query | orderBy:orderByScore:reverseSort">
      <td><span style="color:white">{{$index+1}}</span></td>
      <td>{{team.teamName}}</td>
      <td>{{team.teamLocation}}</td>
      <td>{{team.teamPoints | number:2}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
scoreboard.controller('scoreboardCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

     $scope.orderByScore = 'teamPoints';
     $scope.reverseSort = true;

     $scope.teams = [
          { "teamName": "motorboat skydive", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 35.53},
          { "teamName": "the grinders", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 127.90},
          { "teamName": "team forrec", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 29.46},
          { "teamName": "bikini finger", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 21.98},
          { "teamName": "la familia", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 148.32},
          { "teamName": "darkness is", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 108.88},
          { "teamName": "grinders", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 167.95},
          { "teamName": "discarded youth", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 55.52}
          ];
     };
```

Comment: Can you post u controller too ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular filter removes and adds a new array and updates the ng-repeat, so `$index` will also be updated. Instead you can initialize index, `ng-init="idx=$index+1"` and use it. `ng-init` values are never watched and are not updated as well, but `$index` will change based on the iteration number of the item in the array

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teams  | filter:query | orderBy:orderByScore:reverseSort" ng-init="idx = $index+1">
    <td><span>{{idx}}</span></td>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5N8q4Z?p=preview)**

Since index is critical here in your case as it is the rankings best way to handle this could be to add index from the controller itself.

```
$scope.teams = [
          { "teamName": "motorboat skydive", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 35.53},
          { "teamName": "the grinders", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 127.90},
          { "teamName": "team forrec", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 29.46},
          { "teamName": "bikini finger", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 21.98},
          { "teamName": "la familia", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 148.32},
          { "teamName": "darkness is", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 108.88},
          { "teamName": "grinders", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 167.95},
          { "teamName": "discarded youth", "teamLocation": "1189 King", "teamPoints": 55.52}
          ]
   .sort(function(itm1, itm2){ return itm2.teamPoints - itm1.teamPoints }) //Sort teams

   .map(function(itm, idx){ itm.index = (idx+1); return itm;  }); //assign rankings
```

I used native sort Or just use angular orderByFilter itself in your controller to do it for the initial set (and remove the logic of ng-init variable assignment from the view). So you don't run with run time $index issues.

**[Plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/utKY98?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm just learning Angular as I go along here. I'll have to read up more on ng-init